# recently switch from sqlite to mysql. need to convert some code in c

Tags: mysql, c, api, sqlite

I'm writing C program to access database.
I recently switch from sqlite to mysql.
I'm not familiar with mysql c api, so I need help converting some code.

Below example is executing sql statement with parameter.

sqlite:

```c
char *zSQL = sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT price FROM warehouse WHERE p_ID='%q'", input_value);
sqlite3_prepare_v2(handle,zSQL,-1,&stmt,0);
```

my attempt in mysql:

```c
char zSQL[60] = {'\0'};
int n = 0;

n = sprintf(zSQL, "SELECT price FROM warehouse WHERE p_ID='%s'", input_value);
mysql_real_query(conn, zSQL, n);
```

Another example is parsing result of sql statement to variable

sqlite:

```c
double price_value = 0;
if (sqlite3_step (stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    price_value = sqlite3_column_double (stmt, 0);
}
```

mysql:

```c
MYSQL_ROW row;
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
{
    price_value = atof(row[0]);
}
```

While the code in mysql works for me, but I feel like I'm not utilizing the API enough.
Is there any function in mysql c api which has the same functionality as `sqlite3_mprintf()` and `sqlite3_column_double()` ?

Edit:
My attempt on `mysql_real_escape_string()`:

```c
ulong in_length = strlen(input_value);
char input_esc[(2 * in_length)+1];

mysql_real_escape_string(conn, input_esc, input_value, in_length); 
char sql_stmnt[56] = {'\0'};

n = sprintf(zSQL, "SELECT price FROM warehouse WHERE p_ID='%s'", input_esc);
mysql_real_query(conn, sql_stmnt, n);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first exampe, the short answer is no, you have to do it yourself, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html

```
 unsigned long mysql_real_escape_string(MYSQL *mysql, char *to, const char *from, unsigned long length)
```

The second one, yes, that's the way to go, with some additional check that `row[0]` is indeed of type double.

Alternatively, you can use the prepared statement API which works quite similar to the one in sqlite3.  The key is you provide buffers of type `MYSQL_BIND` and then either bind the inputs to it, or have mysql binding output values there.

Prepared statement documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-prepared-statement-data-structures.html

Comment: I found this [example](http://mysqlresources.com/api/c/690). It is quite similar to mine. Can I just `mysql_real_escape_string()` the `input_value` only?

Comment: Take a look at my post for my attempt in `mysql_real_escape_string()`